# Cascading Style Sheets Optimization

Tags: css, optimization

I wonder about optimization in case:

```
font-weight: normal;
font-weight: 400;
```

Which of this instruction is the most optimal ?

Comment: What makes you think that your font-weight definition is causing a detectable performance reduction?

Answer (score 7):

In this case, don't worry about optimization. You should use `font-weight: normal;`. It is much easier to understand than `font-weight: 400;`.

Since the difference between the two will probably be less than a millisecond or no time at all, you should value readability over tiny useless optimizations here. It is far easier to realize that `font-weight: normal;` means normal weight than it is to realize that `font-weight: 400;` does.

Using `font-weight: normal;` will make debugging your CSS *far* easier than `font-weight: 400;`. You will not ever notice a difference between the two. Also, as noted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692343/cascading-style-sheets-optimization/16692407?noredirect=1#comment24023566_16692407) by Paul D. Waite, should some browser treat these differently, it could cause bugs.

---

In response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692343/cascading-style-sheets-optimization/16692407?noredirect=1#comment24023391_16692407):

> I wonder about commpressing tools for css and i saw taht this tool replace font-weight: 400; insted of font-weight: normal;

That's probably just to reduce the file size. It saves 3 characters, which doesn't seem like much, but it adds up. Never do this in your unminified code though, it will not help with understanding it.

Comment: I'm not talking about readability of css code, i agree with You that font-weight: normal is more readable and i also use it. I wonder about commpressing tools for css and i saw taht this tool replace font-weight: 400; insted of font-weight: normal;

Comment: Of course, if some browser somewhere starts treating `normal` and `400` differently, then you’ve got a free bug along with your 3-byte pre-gzip file save saving.